# Getting Error after using Applovin plugin Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, mobile-ad-mediation, applovin

My App was working perfectly and smoothly without adding the applovin SDK, how do I solve the issue of the problem that I encountered?

Here's my Gradle file (Root)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android' }
    google()
}
dependencies {
                    //4.3.1
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    classpath "com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:3.0.0"
}
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here's my Gradle app level

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'applovin-quality-service'

applovin {
    apiKey "OkvHFuab6SR_8RzKBqWGvaAdGFTuBmTQiITRJzo2fV0PulrwAyX1OfftyR3O9JsC5eGR7vbUp76zHLFI6TQ1FF"
}
```

android {
compileSdk 31

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.app"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
                        //FIREBASE
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
                        //CONSTANT SIZE
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
                        //NEUMORPH
    implementation 'com.github.fornewid:neumorphism:0.3.0'
                        //ANIMATED BOTTOM BAR NAVIGATION
    implementation 'com.github.chetankoli1.BottomNavigation:chetanbottomnavigation:0.0.3'
                        //LOAD IMAGES FROM ONLINE
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.13.0'
                        //CIRCLE IMAGE
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
                        //ADS
    implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:11.4.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

This is the error that i am getting when trying to run the app

```
> Task :app:safedkAdjustInputsDebug FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"API 'MergedFlavor.getApplicationId()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'Variant.getApplicationId()'.\nIt will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.\nGradle Properties must be used to change Variant information.\nFor more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/use-properties.\nTo determine what is calling MergedFlavor.getApplicationId(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.","sources":[{}]}

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Error processing manifest file for variantdebug

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:188)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:174)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
API 'MergedFlavor.getApplicationId()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'Variant.getApplicationId()'.
It will be removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
Gradle Properties must be used to change Variant information.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/use-properties.
To determine what is calling MergedFlavor.getApplicationId(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.

    https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/validation_problems.html#missing_annotation for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'applovin-quality-service' type 'com.safedk.gradleplugin.tasks.AdjustInstrumentationInputsTask' property 'variant' is missing an input or output annotation.
    
    Reason: A property without annotation isn't considered during up-to-date checking.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Add an input or output annotation.
      2. Mark it as @Internal.
```

To make it short, here's the cause of the problem

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Error processing manifest file for variantdebug
```

and,

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'manifestOutputDirectory' for task ':app:processDebugManifest' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessMultiApkApplicationManifest.
```

**Any help is highly appreciable**